# How to consolidate data by domain in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadhseet that looks something like this:

```
Referrer --- Clicks --- Conversions
http://google.com/search?q=hello+world ---- 12 ---- 3
http://george.com ---- 4 ---- 1
http://google.com/search?q=yeah ----- 3 ---- 3
http://george.com/2010/3/this-blog ----- 4 ---- 0
http://www.wave-runner.com/hey ---- 3 ---- 0
```

How can I write a macro that will consolidate it like this:

```
http://google.com/ ---- 15 ---- 6
http://george.com ---- 8 ---- 1
http://www.wave-runner.com/hey ---- 3 ---- 0
```

Comment: What's your criteria for consolidating? In two cases, you've consolidated to the top-level domain (http://google.com) but in the last case, you consolidated to a directory within that domain (http://www.wave-runner.com/hey).

Comment: Good question. I just want to consolidate to the top-level domain.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what those dashes are, but I'll assume they're column breaks.  Make another column and call it Domain.  Put this formula in it.

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("/",A2,FIND("//",A2)+2)),MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)),MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,FIND("/",A2,FIND("//",A2)+2)-FIND("//",A2)-2))
```

Then do a pivot table with Domain in the row field and Clicks and Conversions in the data field.  If those dashes are really dashes, you can do a Data - Text to Columns to split them out into columns first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    ''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
    ''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
    ''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    ''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
    ''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
    ''can be used.
    ''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
    ''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    ''Late binding, so no reference is needed

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


    cn.Open strCon

    strSQL = "SELECT Mid(Referrer & '/',1,Instr(8,Referrer & '/','/')), " _
           & "Sum([Clicks]) As SumClks, Sum([Conversions]) As SumConv " _
           & "FROM [Sheet2$] a " _
           & "GROUP BY Mid(Referrer & '/',1,Instr(8,Referrer & '/','/')) "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```